# include_path not working in httpd.conf

Tags: php, apache-2.4

I have a virtual host set in httpd.conf.  The virtual host resolves properly, but it is ignoring my php_include path directive:

```
php_value include_path .:/var/www/xxx/library/
```

The path works, I copied and pasted it into an ls.  Normally, I'd pursue that further, but the error_log shows me this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): 
   Failed opening required 'api/v1/xxx.php'
   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')
```

So, it isn't even looking in the right place.  Everything else in the vhost is fine, just not taking the PHP include_path properly.  Any pointers?